# Node.js Storing JSON data in array for later use

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I am pretty new working with JSON.
I have a for loop like the following that everytime is executed returns a different `product` (with different `owner_id` and `name` fields)

```
for (/* some condition here */) {
    product = {
         owner_id: somevalue,
         name: somevalue
    }
}
```

I need to store all the different occurrences of `product` for a later use. I was thinking about using an array, so I changed the above code to this:

```
var selectedProducts = [];
for (/* some condition here */) {
    product = {
         owner_id: somevalue,
         name: somevalue
    }
    selectedProducts.push(product);
    selectedProducts.push(JSON.stringify(product));
}
```

But what I get is an array with `undefined` content.

What I need to achieve later is calling a for cycle like the following

```
for(var i = 0; i < selectedProducts.length; i++) {
    console.log(selectedProducts[i]); // Will print the single JSON object
}
```

How can I achieve such a result?

Comment: Why are you not writing `selectedProducts.push(product)`?

Comment: I am actually doing it. Sorry. That is because I changed the name from `post` to `product` to clarify here on stackoverflow.

Comment: @Oliver I corrected it. Thanks for notifying me.

Comment: You need to post a larger code excerpt, because there is no problem with the code you have provided.

Comment: I am doing some tests right now and I actually see that selectedProducts.length returns `0`

Comment: Are you sure the first for isn't in a callback function? Seems to be the main cause of things being undefined in node

Comment: Absolutely @AlexLogan

Answer (score 0):

You could store the `selectedProducts` array on the session (see [docs](https://github.com/expressjs/session)).

```
var selectedProducts = [];
for (/* some condition here */) {
    product = {
         owner_id: somevalue,
         name: somevalue
    }
    selectedProducts.push(product);
}

req.session.selectedProducts = selectedProducts;
```

Then get the array back from the session.

```
for(var i = 0; i < req.session.selectedProducts.length; i++) {
    console.log(req.session.selectedProducts[i]); // Will print the single JSON object
}
```

Comment: I don't think I will need a session to do it, since I need to do everything in the same POST request middleware

Comment: Ok I didn't realise it was in the same post